# Hypotheses for Leray's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is it not enough, in the hypotheses for Leray's theorem, to assume that $H^q(U_a, \mathcal{F}) = 0$, for all $q > 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Take $X = S^2$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{U} = \{U_N, U_S\}$, where $U_N$ is the complement of the North Pole and $U_S$ is the complement of the South Pole. Then  $H^2(\mathcal{U}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, by virtue of the fact that there are only two open subsets, and so there are no [$2$-chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Chainz). But $H^2(S^2, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Dear Kevin, thanks also for keeping more mature users up-to-date on musicological questions: things seem to have moved on since Tchaikovsky (my favourite composer). And +1, of course.